# Help with a simple script to togle 2 images, thumbnail and fullsize

Tags: javascript, image, toggle

I am a newbie in javascript. I have a script like this:

```
<html>
    <head>          
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var x= '<img id="im" src="thumbnail.gif">';

            switch (x)
            {
            case x=='document.getElementById("im")':
            document.getElementById('im').outerHTML='<img id="im" src="fullsize.gif">';
            break;
            case x!='document.getElementById("im")':
            document.getElementById('im').outerHTML='<img id="im" src="thumbnail.gif">';
            break;
            default: x;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span onclick="switch()">
            <img id="im" src="thumbnail.gif">
        </span>     
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to keep it simple, but also make it work using the switch function. I didn't used them im my script. I am NOT looking for a slide show, also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, you don't want quotes around `'document.getElementById("im")'` since that means you're looking for that string.  Two, case statements don't work like that, the syntax is `case value`, not `case expression` (an expression being your `==`).  Three, you don't have an actual function call.  You're calling `switch` which doesn't do anything...

Try something like:

```
function swap(){
    switch(document.getElementById('im').outerHTML){
        case x:
            ...
            break;

        default:
            ...
            break;
    }
}

...

<span onclick="swap();">
```

which should fix your existing code.  Or the "proper" way of doing this is more like:

```
function swap(){
   var node = document.getElementById('im');
   node.src = node.src.indexOf('fullsize')>=0 ? 'thumbnail.gif' : 'fullsize.gif';
}

...

<span onclick="swap();">
```

Oh, and I fixed your original question.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I've already tested your code in IE, FF and Opera. It works great. I have not used indexOF before.